# Получение списка пользователей Zabbix для оповещения, по известному триггеру

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Есть известный сработваший триггер. По нему мы можем получить группу оборудования и хост:

```
mysql> select groups.groupid,hosts.hostid from triggers inner join functions on triggers.triggerid=functions.triggerid inner join items on items.itemid=functions.itemid inner join hosts on hosts.hostid=items.hostid  inner join hosts_groups on hosts_groups.hostid=hosts.hostid inner join groups on groups.groupid=hosts_groups.groupid where triggers.triggerid=15266;
+---------+--------+
| groupid | hostid |
+---------+--------+
|      10 |  10250 |
|      24 |  10250 |
+---------+--------+
```

Так-же у нас есть таблица actions, откуда мы можем взять каких пользователей и какие группы оповещать в случае проблем:

```
mysql> select actions.actionid,actions.name,opmessage_usr.userid,opmessage_grp.usrgrpid from opmessage inner join operations on operations.operationid=opmessage.operationid inner join actions on actions.actionid=operations.actionid left join opmessage_usr on opmessage_usr.operationid=operations.operationid left join opmessage_grp on opmessage_grp.operationid=operations.operationid left join opcommand_hst on opcommand_hst.operationid=operations.operationid left join opgroup on opgroup.operationid=operations.operationid left join opcommand_grp on opcommand_grp.operationid=operations.operationid left join optemplate on optemplate.operationid=operations.operationid left join conditions on conditions.actionid=operations.actionid limit 10;
+----------+------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| actionid | name                                           | userid | usrgrpid |
+----------+------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+
|        3 | Report problems to Zabbix administrators       |   NULL |        7 |
|        3 | Report problems to Zabbix administrators       |   NULL |        7 |
|        4 | Report not supported items                     |   NULL |        7 |
|        5 | Report not supported low level discovery rules |   NULL |        7 |
|        6 | Report unknown triggers                        |   NULL |        7 |
|        8 | Проблемы с КТВ                     |      3 |     NULL |
|        8 | Проблемы с КТВ                     |      3 |     NULL |
|       10 | Проблемы в уцвц     |   NULL |       13 |
|       10 | Проблемы в цвцув     |   NULL |       13 |
|       11 | Для сисадминов                    |   NULL |       18 |
+----------+------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+
```

Не могу найти из какой таблицы взять данные, для того чтобы связать эти данные. Т.е. кому отправляются оповещения в случае страбатывания триггера.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в этом духе:

```
select userid from (select users_groups.userid from operations inner join opmessage_grp on opmessage_grp.operationid=operations.operationid inner join users_groups on opmessage_grp.usrgrpid=users_groups.usrgrpid where operations.actionid in (select actionid from conditions where conditiontype=2 and value=15266 union all select actionid from conditions where conditiontype=0 and value in (SELECT groups.groupid FROM triggers INNER JOIN functions ON triggers.triggerid=functions.triggerid INNER JOIN items ON items.itemid=functions.itemid INNER JOIN hosts ON hosts.hostid=items.hostid INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts_groups.hostid=hosts.hostid INNER JOIN groups ON groups.groupid=hosts_groups.groupid WHERE triggers.triggerid=15266) union all select actionid from conditions where conditiontype=1 and value in (SELECT hosts.hostid FROM triggers INNER JOIN functions ON triggers.triggerid=functions.triggerid INNER JOIN items ON items.itemid=functions.itemid INNER JOIN hosts ON hosts.hostid=items.hostid INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts_groups.hostid=hosts.hostid INNER JOIN groups ON groups.groupid=hosts_groups.groupid WHERE triggers.triggerid=15266)) union all select opmessage_usr.userid from operations inner join opmessage_usr on opmessage_usr.operationid=operations.operationid where operations.actionid in (select actionid from conditions where conditiontype=2 and value=15266 union all select actionid from conditions where conditiontype=0 and value in (SELECT groups.groupid FROM triggers INNER JOIN functions ON triggers.triggerid=functions.triggerid INNER JOIN items ON items.itemid=functions.itemid INNER JOIN hosts ON hosts.hostid=items.hostid INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts_groups.hostid=hosts.hostid INNER JOIN groups ON groups.groupid=hosts_groups.groupid WHERE triggers.triggerid=15266) union all select actionid from conditions where conditiontype=1 and value in (SELECT hosts.hostid FROM triggers INNER JOIN functions ON triggers.triggerid=functions.triggerid INNER JOIN items ON items.itemid=functions.itemid INNER JOIN hosts ON hosts.hostid=items.hostid INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts_groups.hostid=hosts.hostid INNER JOIN groups ON groups.groupid=hosts_groups.groupid WHERE triggers.triggerid=15266))) as us group by userid
```

- по известному triggerid получаеам список пользователей для оповещения